# Don't find my file.properties

Tags: java, file, properties, call

I try a lot of thinks to find the fail but i don't know how I can do it. my code is:

```
    //DominioLlamadaRedSys.java

    Properties d = new Properties();
    InputStream entrada = null;
    try {


        entrada = new FileInputStream("prop/datosApp.properties");
        d.load(entrada);

        System.out.println(d.getProperty("TXD.endPointUrl")); 

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println("ERROR: "+ ex.getMessage());

    } finally {
        if (entrada != null) {
        try {
            entrada.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        }
    }
```

I call the file inside a class in "com.rsi.secpay.dominio" and this always catch the same exception (don't find the file), I had try to quit "prop/" (just "datosApp.properties" ) with properties files like this:

[image]

Comment: Your code is in eclipse. right

Comment: right, is in eclipse

Comment: use classloader to get a file path.

Comment: What's your goal here? Once your application is deployed and installed on an end-user computed, do you want to read properties from a file on the end-user's hard drive, or do you want to read properties from a file bundled inside the jar file containing your application?

Comment: in the .jar!! you can see the file in the imagen "datosApp.properties"

Answer (score 3):

If your *prop* package is in your classpath, you can get the stream using the classloader:

```
InputStream is = DominioLlamadaRedSys.class.getResourceAsStream("/prop/datosApp.properties");
```